# How do you preview your app in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to learn how to build an application. I saw  this video on YouTube that was titled How to Make a Web app in 7 minutes.  He built this app using the UserInterface but I don't see this option when I am trying to build my own app. The link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlF1mf6s94w I am not affilated with this guy but when I go to file I don't see this option available. Trying to figure how to do so that I can see what it all looks like and adjust as I go.

Comment: first guess : video is more then a year old. They update the app engine code VERY frequently.  Maybe that option doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the GUI Builder. This feature has been discontinued on October 2013, [as written here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset).

Another thing : You're making a confusion between Google Apps Script and Google App Engine. The video describes how to build a webapp with Google Apps Script, which is a scripting language with extended capabilities accessible from Google Drive. It is based on Javascript.

It is different from Google App Engine, which is another way to build webapps in Java, PHP, Python or Go. It is more complex than Apps Script but also more powerful.

You cannot deploy an Apps Script code on App Engine, and you cannot deploy an App Engine code on Apps Script. Those are two different technologies.

- [Click here for a quick start about Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)
- [Click here for App Engine's documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)